# How to set high on rise edge, low on fall edge?

Tags: digital-logic

I have two switches which turn on a bulb, and basically I want "the last one wins" scenario.

```
Initial SW1: 0, SW2: 0

SW1: 0->1 Out: 1

SW2: 0->1 Out: 1

SW2: 1->0 Out: 0

SW2: 0->1 Out: 1

SW1: 1->0 Out 0
```

The logic I need basically is on rising edge of any input, set output high, and on falling edge of any input, set output low.

However, all flip flops (that I know) can only do rise edge or fall edge, so how do I implement this?

Comment: It can be solved in 'discrete' logic, but the solution I would choose today is asingle chip small $1 mircocontroller (eg. ATtiny13). The 'discrete' logic would probably involve a state machine, using EXOR ports to detect the toggling inputs and flip flops to keep current state. At least two packages, lots of wiring that can go wrong ... etc.

Comment: @jippie Thanks, never knew that microcontrollers that cheap existed!

Comment: The logic requires 4 states so either enables until Both arrived before Reset by either leaving so two FF's required or 2 storage cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use SPDT switches, you could use old-school asynchronous (aka hairball) logic, as below. Eg. two 74HC00, a SIP 8-resistor pullup and 4 capacitors. The same thing is possible with SPST switches by differentiating both edges after debouncing.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjGOzO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But personally, I'd just program a small micro. PIC12F509 or something like that, as jippie says, and add some filtering so noise doesn't trigger it etc.